# javascript how to add function to an object

Tags: javascript

In below syntax I have requestContext object defined as following:

```
requestContext = {
        nameValidator: {
            validate : function() {
                return [];
            }
        }
   };
```

But for testing purposes I want to make `requestContext.functionOne().functionTwo()` defined. 
here is what I have tried but it is not working:

```
        let functionTwo = function() {
            return {};
        };
        requestContext.functionOne = function(){
            return functionTwo;
        };
```

Comment: `fucntionOne` Spelling matters in programming.

Comment: You also forgot to invoke `functionTwo` when inside `functionOne`.

Comment: @CertainPerformance: wrongly typed here ... but in my code it is typed correctly

Comment: Given what you have, the execution would be `requestContext.functionOne()()`.  The response is a function, so you'd just execute it.

Comment: I think Taplar’s got the right answer

Comment: Or make functionOne return `{ functionTwo: functionTwo }`.  Then you could do `functionOne().functionTwo()`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried returning an object containing the inner function like below

```
requestContext.functionOne = function() { return {functionTwo}; }
```

with this you should be able to call

```
requestContext.functionOne().functionTwo()
```